# Can I get more than 4kb of data from a website database to an Android phone using GCM?

Tags: cordova, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-pushplugin

Hey I am planning to do my final year project on PhoneGap. The idea is to build a prescription viewer app along with a pill reminder. The patient will consult a doctor, who will upload the prescription (medicine, dosage, time) to a website. From the website, it is sent to the patient’s Android phone using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), and using that data a reminder is created. I have a plan to include a feature like receiving a scanned report from the hospital (.JPG format) and information about the patients from database.

So what I want to know is whether it is possible to get all the information from the website database to the Android phone’s database using GCM? (I found that only 4kb data can be sent.) If not, is there any other way through which I can get all the details from hospital website database to user's Android phone database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is 4 kilo byte restriction. This is enough for applications such as instant messaging but for applications needing to transfer larger amounts of file, you need to use what Android docs call [*"send-to-sync" messages*](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#s2s). As the name indicates you only send the push notification to notify the app about new content to be loaded. This information can contain also link (or id etc.) to resource or just plain information that there is something new waiting. Client then uses AJAX to retrieve this data via HTTP requests as plain mobile app would work. The notification is only telling when there is new content to be loaded.